# (slow edge coloring) how to avoid looping all tip.labels (package ape)

Tags: r

I am coloring edges in phylo trees generated with some functions from "ape"

Since I've always programmed in C, I still find it hard to stop thinking in a loop-like manner.

The only way I can think of doing this is by (1) looping all the tip.labels (IDs), (2) finding out which edges belong to them and (3) setting the desired color.

This is done 1 by 1 and therefore is incredibly slow for big trees:

```
tsampltime.rooted=structure(list(edge = structure(c(24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 25L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
24L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 34L, 36L, 
36L, 34L, 37L, 37L, 1L, 2L, 12L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 6L, 27L, 5L, 
28L, 3L, 4L, 29L, 7L, 30L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 31L, 13L, 32L, 21L, 
22L, 33L, 20L, 34L, 35L, 14L, 15L, 36L, 16L, 17L, 37L, 18L, 19L
), .Dim = c(36L, 2L)), Nnode = 14L, tip.label = c("0", "2325", 
"55304", "124953", "72254", "66507", "85089", "110256", "123265", 
"97350", "123721", "36770", "48692", "110612", "97224", "104337", 
"124625", "128499", "120928", "88404", "73335", "75059", "17928"
), edge.length = c(0, 0.953297, 8.054944, 4.4120893, 9.173083, 
1.409346, 3.752752, 0.483517, 4.620875, 0.582417, 0.510989, 12.4862723, 
6.291209, 1.920329, 3.071429, 4.5027528, 5.497248, 2.777472, 
5.5274749, 8.414843, 2.5467017, 3.79121, 3.824171, 3.961538, 
3.804944, 2.126375, 1.75275, 1.93956, 3.3516546, 1.57418, 2.31319, 
2.22528, 4.0384651, 3.898348, 2.722523, 1.87088)), .Names = c("edge", 
"Nnode", "tip.label", "edge.length"), class = "phylo", order = "cladewise")
   ... 
#distValuesPerId[,] has [LABELID,COLOR]
distValuesPerId=source('http://ubuntuone.com/5y7ZYCWfE73T5lhnUpmeXc')
...
uniqueIDs=unique(tree$tip.label)
distTrdsampledcol <-rep("black", length(tree$edge)) #init in black
for(i in uniqueIDs) { #(1)
    a= c(which(tree$tip.label==i)) 
    b= which(tree$edge[,2]== a) #(2)
    distTrdsampledcol [ b ] <- distValuesPerId[i,2] #(3)
}
...
#plot(tree, edge.color=distTrdsampledcol)
```

Can anyone  help me to rethink this? Is there a more efficient of doing this?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

j

Comment: Use `dput(tree)` on a small tree to give us some sample data.

Comment: @nograpes, here it is:


[dput(distValuesPerId)](http://ubuntuone.com/5y7ZYCWfE73T5lhnUpmeXc) 


[dput(tree)](http://ubuntuone.com/3GdyoX4ETlU5cDuRpPMfcN) 


[plot(tree)](http://ubuntuone.com/5ikA8OIrN9nQrpIgpzTehg) 


thanks for the reply

Comment: You can actually just post your image inside your question, and you should also copy the code to create your tree there as well. I'll do it for you now. It is not a good idea to post a `data.frame` with 120,000 rows. You should have taken only the colours you need out of that data.frame, and posted that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be overthinking this. Just subselect the colours you need from your giant colour `data.frame`.

```
plot(tree,edge.color=distValuesPerId[tree$tip.label,2])
```

Try out the examples list on `?plot.phylo`, they have a ton of examples of really cool things you can do with your trees, including colouring. It might give you some ideas.

---

After seeing your comment, I realized, that I had misunderstood the question. This should do what you want without loops:

```
cols=distValuesPerId[match(tree$tip.label[tree$edge[,2]],distValuesPerId[,1]),2]
my.cols=ifelse(is.na(cols),'black',cols)
plot(tree, edge.color=my.cols)
```

Breaking it down:

```
# Find the tip labels associated with each edge, NA if it is not an edge to a tip
edge.tip.labels=tree$tip.label[tree$edge[,2]]
# Match each of those tip labels to the label column in your colur data frame
edge.rows=match(edge.tip.labels,distValuesPerId[,1])
# Find the colour for each of those rows
cols=distValuesPerId[edge.rows,2]
# Where it is NA, convert it to 'black' (where it is not a 'tip edge')
my.cols=ifelse(is.na(cols),'black',cols)
```

Comment: your suggestion assumes that distValuesPerId gives the edge "index" given an ID (label), but that is not the case... one has to look for the edge index that corresponds to the desired ID

i agree i may be over thinking, but cant sort a better way
ill have a look at the examples

thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood the question. See my updated response.